# Autolayout(xcode 6,swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In I phone 5s simulator its working fine! I have one label,one image view and one button.As you can click on the link and see the picture now so i tell you that I used my image view as a background and the label is in the middle and the button is in the lower middle so i want that to look same in all the devices. i don't know anything about constraints.I am using Xcode 6

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2z_d4wEKPEFLV9RNFVlR3A5SFppa0tJT2tiQkQwVVVVTDVz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't think that link does what you want it to do.

Comment: @marosoaie check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at this youtube tutorial. I learned how to make the constrains by watching it. The tutorial teaches how to make the similar layout as you required.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpMzEmF-xZM

Hope this is helpful~

Comment: I done my autolayout with this tutorial right now and it works But in iphone simulator 4s,5 and ipad2 its showing error Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0) i dont know why it is showing this error @AresLee

Comment: @Motivationgym5 I think the reason is the architecture differences between iPhone 5s(including above models) and older devices. I have gotten similar error when I developed a game by using Unity, which is a popular game engine. I solved that by changing the compatibility settings from Unity. However, your case is the native Xcode project, and I just did some research online about the native platform issue. I think the link below can give you some hints. Link: http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2a888t/getting_weird_error/

Comment: thanks man its working now no crashing and se my one more problem if you can solve check in my profile that termination problem

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout is the tool used to make UI look similar across all devices, you should try to learn it if you want to continue to develop IOS apps. The concepts are pretty basic and are used throughout other languages.

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1) is useful if you want to create the auto layout using storyboards.

[This tutorial](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/) is useful if you are making the view programmatically. I tend to use code for auto layout but it is just a preference, storyboards is fairly simple so I would suggest that. If you are going to do it in code a is to forget setting the autoresizing mask into constraints to false. You have to set this property on all the views you want to use auto layout for.

```
view2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Background ImageView
Select Image ->Pin->Uncheck Constraints to margin-> select top,bottom,left,right.

Button
Select Button-> Pin->Uncheck Constraints to margin->select bottom,left,right,Height.

label
Select label->Align->Center horizontally and Center Vertically in Container.
Pin->Width,Height.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working for iPhone 5 but not another layout then this is probably happening.

There are demensions in the centre of the lower tab bar of story boards

There are screen size settings in the story board and regular*regular is the only one that is universal to all orientations and sizes of the ios device. if you set constraints while viewing in regular by compact (landscape for 5.5 inch iPhone) then those constraints will only be apply to 5.5 inch iPhones in landscape and if you tried running on a smaller iPod it would be as if you never set the constraints. the constraints for the 5.5 inch iPhone would not apply to the small iPod

if constraints were made in compact by compact and you were viewing the story board in say regular by compact then you would get an error saying that things are misplace and will not appear in the same at runtime. view the storyboard in the same dimensions that you set the constraints and you should not have an issue.

There is an option to simulate the device you want to run on specifically in storyboard and it can be say only 5.5 inch iPhones or something, whatever device.

go to paul hegarty developing iOS apps with swift on iTunes you if you want to learn more. He is a good source.